# Xcode Storyboard New Item Full Width and Height

Tags: xcode, object, storyboard, size, dimensions

When I drag an object to a view in the Xcode Storyboard, it assumes the full width and height of the containing view, rather than the default dimensions. For instance, I drag a UIButton to an iPad View, and suddenly it's 1024x768 pixels, and for some reason, the width and height properties are grayed out in the configuration window with the ruler on the right. Any ideas why that is and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you dragging it onto a view, or just into a gray area?

Comment: I am dragging it onto a view, although its background does appear gray.

Comment: So onto a view controller? You should add a view first and then put the button on the view.

Comment: Oh god, right! I added a View object, and now I can add sub-objects. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! I posted an official answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our comments above, just add a view to the view controller first, then add the button.